# Adjusting the position of inline image inside div tag

Tags: css, html, layout

my problem is related with the position of the image it is positioned just above the position of input box . i want it to be in same line as input box is

```
<div style="display: table; margin: 0 auto; margin-top: 10px">
    <input id="searchip" type="text" maxlength="30" autofocus="" size="50" name="textnew" style="height: 20px">
    <img src="images/savedomain.png">
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you need is

```
img {
    vertical-align: top;
}
```

[**Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/G2Djj/)